# Error Installing Riak

Tags: key-value, riak, leveldb, nosql

We are trying to install Riak as per the steps mentioned in the website: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/installing/source/
but we are getting this error:

```
Compiling /users/username/riak-2.1.1/deps/syslog/c_src/syslog_drv.c
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
ERROR: compile failed while processing /users/username/riak-2.1.1/deps/syslog:    rebar_abort
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Any suggestion on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The error was resolved on moving to a different machine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The problem seemed to be with the open stack cloud vm with Ubuntu 15.04. As soon as we moved to 14.04 LTS, bare-metal, R320 configuration - the error was resolved.